# How to Use ProbabilityScalePlot with Censored Data?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, fitting

I am trying to reproduce a ProbabilityScalePlot of censored data shown [here](http://www.weibull.nl/weibullstatistics.htm) (see Sample Analysis Plot). Here is my Mathematica code. First I deal with the uncensored case.

```
probscaleplotFix = 
Graphics[Append[First@#, Epilog /. Options[#, Epilog]], 
FilterRules[Options[#], Except[Epilog]]] &;
SetOptions[ProbabilityScalePlot, 
DisplayFunction -> 
probscaleplotFix]; (* Needed to fix a software bug, see solution \
by Alexey Popkov on StackExchange *)

data = {30, 49, 82, 90, 96};
distA = EstimatedDistribution[data, 
WeibullDistribution[a, b], {{a, 3}, {b, 50}}]
plot1 = Plot[PDF[distA, t], {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time", "PDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Distribution 1 (no censoring)", PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Plot 1]

```
plot2 = ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Weibull", 
PlotRange -> {{10, 200}, {1, 90}}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time", "CDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"ProbabilityScalePlot for Distribution 1 (no censoring)", 
GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Plot 2]

So far so good . . . now for the censored data.

```
eventdata = 
EventData[{30, 49, 82, 90, 96, 10, 45, 100}, {None, None, None, None,
None, Right, Right, Right}]

dist2 = EstimatedDistribution[eventdata, 
WeibullDistribution[a2, b2], {{a2, 3}, {b2, 50}}]

plot3 = Plot[PDF[dist2, t], {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time", "PDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Distribution 2 (censoring)", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot 3]

```
plot4 = ProbabilityScalePlot[dist2, "Weibull", 
PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time", "CDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> "ProbabilityScale Plot for Distribution 2 (censoring)"]
```

ProbabilityScalePlot::estmd: Unable to estimate a reference distribution from the data. >>

```
plot5 = ProbabilityScalePlot[eventdata, "Weibull", 
PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time", "CDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> "ProbabilityScale Plot for Distribution 2 (censoring)"]
```

ProbabilityScalePlot::ldata: EventData[8] is not a valid dataset, distribution, or a valid list of datasets and distributions. >>

Can someone tell me how to produce the ProbabilityScalePlot for either eventdata or dist2 ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProbabilityScalePlot` doesn't support censored data for now. However, you can plot censored data as regular data

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[eventdata["InputData"], "Weibull", 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time", "CDF"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "ProbabilityScale Plot for Distribution 2 (censoring)"]
```

[image]

Or extract data without censoring

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[
 Pick[eventdata["InputData"], eventdata["CensoringIndicators"], 0], 
 "Weibull", PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "CDF"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "ProbabilityScale Plot for Distribution 2 (censoring)"]
```

[image]

Comment: much appreciated, your solution meets my needs.